# Deleting a file from GridFS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, gridfs

I'm reading GridFS's docs and I'm not sure I'm understanding it. It says right here https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1.4/examples/gridfs.js#L75 that I should delete a file using it's name. 
But that's just both insane and stupid. Two files with the same name can coexist perfectly inside the same collection by having different `_id`.
There should be a way to delete files by their `_id` instead of by their name, but I can't find it.

My question is: has anybody delete files from GridFS using ids instead of names? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Node.JS but if you want to remove file using `_id` you should use `delete` and as far as I can tell it is implemented in Node.JS driver: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1.4/lib/mongodb/gridfs/grid.js#L95

Comment: I tried that but it says there is no method ```delete```, and I can't see it on the docs page: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/gridstore.html

Comment: Maybe this http://blog.nodeknockout.com/post/35215400231/a-primer-for-gridfs-using-the-mongo-db-driver will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/grid.html#delete

Wasn't looking in the right place.

@zero323 you were right :)

Answer (score 0):

The [GridFSBucket API](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/GridFSBucket.html#delete) on the [mongo nodejs driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) defines a delete method which accepts an ID parameter.